# Probability generating function

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

X and Y are independent random variables having poisson distribution with parameters a and b respectively. By using probability generating function, prove that X + Y have a poisson distribution and give it's parameter

Comment: Welcome to CV! Since you’re new here, you may want to take our tour, which has information for new users.  Since this looks like homework (apologies if it's not), please add the [self-study] tag and read its wiki. Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you is grounds for closing. If this is self-study rather than homework, let us know, and... it's still a good idea to show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

So the PGF of a discrete random variable X is defined as $E[z^X]$. By the law of the unconscious statistician, the expectation of a function of $X$ is the sum (over the support of the random variable) of the function times the PDF (PMF in this case). For the Poisson distribution this works out to

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty z^x \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} = e^{-\lambda} \sum_{x=0}^\infty z^x \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}$$

Now remember that the Taylor expansion of $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$

Also, much like the MGF, the PGF $G(z)$ has the property that if 2 random variables are $X$ and $Y$ independent, and $S = X+Y$, then $G_S(z) = G_X(z)G_Y(z)$.

With these two properties you should be able to deduce the PGF of the sum.